# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo un dataset de 21071445 filas x 29 columnas que se llama vir.blast.
Por cuestiones técnicas no puedo subirlo aquí:

Al querer graficarlo con ggplot utilizando el siguiente código:

```
 ggplot<-ggplot(vir.blast, aes(x = bitscore, fill = read, colour = read)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.25, adjust = 4) + 
    xlim(0, 350) +
    geom_vline(data = mu.pe.bs, aes(xintercept = grp.mean, 
                                    color = factor(read)), 
               linetype = "dashed") + 
    theme_minimal() 

  ggplot + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                 panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
 Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Este error no me salía anteriormente y no he cambiado el tipo de data.frame.
¿Qué esstoy realizando mal? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, tras mucho indagar he visto que el problema era la clase de la variable a representar. Esta necesita estar en formato factor, por lo que lo he arregalado con la función: vir.blast$read <- as.factor(vir.blast$read) y ya ha graficado el resultado.